# How to change the numbering of multiple check-boxes dynamically depending upon user selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 check-boxes. When user selects the first check-box then a label appears "a)." beside it. On the selection of a second check-box, this label changes to "b)." if it is placed lower in the ordering of the check-box's compared to the new selection, and the new check-box gets the labeling "a)." and vice versa.

I have found a way to do this by using binary approach, where I check if 1st, 2nd is selected then 3rd is "c)." if not then "b)." or "a)." but this logic becomes too large and inefficient when a large no. of check-boxes come in.

Can some one help me find a better logic?

Here is a sample code

```
var a= optionA.header.CheckBox4.rawValue;
 var b= optionB.header.CheckBox4.rawValue;
 var c= optionC.header.CheckBox4.rawValue;
 var d= optionD.header.CheckBox4.rawValue; 
 if(this.rawValue == 1)
 {
    if(a==0 && b==0 && c==0 && d==0)
      optionE.number = "c)";
    else if(a==0 && b==0 && c==0 && d==1)
      optionE.number = "d)";
    else if(a==0 && b==0 && c==1 && d==0)
      optionE.number = "d)";    
    else if(a==0 && b==1 && c==0 && d==0)
      optionE.number = "d)";  
    else if(a==1 && b==0 && c==0 && d==0)
      optionE.number = "d)";  
    else if(a==1 && b==1 && c==0 && d==0)
      optionE.number = "e)";
    else if(a==1 && b==0 && c==1 && d==0)
      optionE.number = "e)";    
    else if(a==1 && b==0 && c==0 && d==1)
      optionE.number = "e)";  
    else if(a==0 && b==1 && c==0 && d==1)
      optionE.number = "e)";  
    else if(a==0 && b==1 && c==1 && d==0)
      optionE.number = "e)";  
    else if(a==0 && b==0 && c==1 && d==1)
      optionE.number = "e)";    
    else if(a==1 && b==1 && c==1 && d==0)
      optionE.number = "f)";    
    else if(a==1 && b==0 && c==1 && d==1)
      optionE.number = "f)";    
    else if(a==1 && b==1 && c==0 && d==1)
      optionE.number = "f)";    
    else if(a==0 && b==1 && c==1 && d==1)
      optionE.number = "f)";    
    else if(a==1 && b==1 && c==1 && d==1)
      optionE.number = "g)";    
 }
 else
 {
    optionE.number = "";    
 }
```

Comment: How do we execute your code ?

Comment: This is a javascript being used in Adobe Livecycle.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithmus of your code can be replaced by:

```
switch(a+b+c+d) {
case 0: optionE.number = "c)"; break;
case 1: optionE.number = "d)"; break;
case 2: optionE.number = "e)"; break;
case 3: optionE.number = "f)"; break;
case 4: optionE.number = "g)"; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really meant, as I understood, newest checked checkbox is 'a', next newest is 'b', ....

If my understanding is correct, you may try this:

```js
var
cbArr = [],
charArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.is(':checked')) { // If checked, add element to end of array
    cbArr.push(this);
  } else {
   cbArr.splice(cbArr.indexOf(this), 1) // If not checked, remove element
  }

  $(':checkbox ~ label').text('');
  $.each(cbArr, function(i, v) {
    var charIdx = cbArr.length - i - 1; // Get letter index
    $(v).next('label').text(charArr[charIdx]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-1">
<label for="cb-1"></label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-2">
<label for="cb-2"></label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-3">
<label for="cb-3"></label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-4">
<label for="cb-4"></label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-5">
<label for="cb-5"></label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-6">
<label for="cb-6"></label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-7">
<label for="cb-7"></label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-8">
<label for="cb-8"></label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-9">
<label for="cb-9"></label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb-10">
<label for="cb-10"></label>
<br>
```

Comment: Hi, let me tell you that you are giving javascript code that supports html, where as my code is for Adobe Livecycle, which also uses javascript. I am not entirely sure if this is implementable in it.